# How to create multiple "has_many through" associations through one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm building a martial arts related database, currently I have the following associations set up:

- Student has_and_belongs_to_many :styles
- Style has_many :ranks
- Student has_many :ranks, through: :gradings (and vice versa)

I'm generating a form as follows, depending on the student's styles:

[image: grading form]

So the headings are generated by the `Style` model (Tai Chi, Karate...), then their rankings listed below (taken from the `Rank` model), and the "Dojo" and "Date" fields should belong to the `Grading` model once created.

**The question**: I know how to build a form that creates one association (or one association + its children), but how do I build a form that creates multiple associations at once?

Also, what would be a clean way to implement the following:

1. Only lines which are ticked become associations
2. Dojo and date must be filled in for ticked lines to save successfully
3. If a line is unticked it will destroy any previously created associations

This is what I've currently implemented to retrieve the correct records:

```
class GradingsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_sensei!

  def index
    @student = Student.includes(:styles).find(params[:student_id])
    @ranks = Rank.for_student_styles(@student)
    split_ranks_by_style
  end

  private

  def split_ranks_by_style
    @karate = @ranks.select_style("Karate")
    @tai_chi = @ranks.select_style("Tai Chi")
    @weaponry = @ranks.select_style("Weaponry")
  end
end

# Rank model
def self.for_student_styles(student)
  includes(:style).where("styles.id in (?)", student.styles.map(&:id))
end

def self.select_style(style)
  all.map { |r| r if r.style.name == style }.compact
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complicated forms like this are best handled in a service object initiated in the primary resource's `create` or `update` action. This allows you to easily find where the logic is happening afterwards. In this case it looks like you can kick off your service object in your `GradingsController`. I also prefer formatting a lot of the data in the markup, to make the handling easier in the service object. This can be done a'la rails, by passing a name like `"grade[style]"` and `"grade[rank]"`. This will format your params coming in as a convenient hash: `{grade: {style: "karate", rank: "3"}}`. That hash can be passed to your service object to be parsed through.

Without really grasping the full extent of your specific requirements, let's put together an example form:

```
<%= form_for :grading, url: gradings_path do |f| %>
  <h1><%= @rank.name %></h1>
  <%- @grades.each do |grade| %>
    <div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "grade[#{grade.id}][id]", grade.id %>
      <%= check_box_tag "grade[#{grade.id}][active]" %>
      ...
      <%= text_field_tag "grade[#{grade.id}][date]" %>
    </div>
  <%- end %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<%- end %>
```

With a form like this, you get your params coming into the controller looking something like this:

```
"grade"=>{
  "1"=>{"id"=>"1", "active"=>"1", "date"=>"2013-06-21"},
  "3"=>{"id"=>"3", "date"=>"2013-07-01"}
}
```

Nicely formatted for us to hand off to our service object. Keeping our controller nice and clean:

```
class GradingsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # ...
  end

  def create
    builder = GradeBuilder.new(current_user, params['grade'])
    if builder.run
      redirect_to gradings_path
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Something went wrong!' # maybe even builder.error_message
      render :action => :index
    end
  end

end
```

So now we just need to put any custom logic into our builder, I'd probably recommend just making a simple ruby class in your `/lib` directory. It could look something like this:

```
class GradeBuilder

  attr_reader :data, :user

  def self.initialize(user, params={})
    @user = user
    @data = params.values.select{|param| param['active'].present? }
  end

  def run
    grades = data.each{|entry| build_grade(entry)}
    return false if grades.empty?
  end

  private

  def build_grade(entry)
    grade = Grade.find(entry['id'])
    rank = grade.rankings.create(student_id: user, date: entry['date'])
  end

end
```

There will obviously need a lot more work to pass all the specific data you need from the form, and extra logic in the `GradeBuilder` to handle edge cases, but this will give you a framework to handle this problem in a maintainable and extensible way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I ended up implementing something similar once I remembered I could format the hash. The service object makes everything a lot cleaner though!